# Начал делать новый проект в Unity и VSCode начал выдавать ошибку

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio-code

Вот сама ошибка

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 29.09.2020, 01:13:37
    Target: d:\UProj\W&B\W&B.sln

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: c:\Users\пека\.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.23.2\.omnisharp\1.37.1\OmniSharp.exe
    PID: 8444

System.ArgumentException: OmniSharp only supports being launched with a directory path or a path to a solution (.sln) file.
��� ��ࠬ���: path
   � OmniSharp.Services.OmniSharpEnvironment..ctor(String path, Int32 hostPid, LogLevel logLevel, String[] additionalArguments) � D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\Services\OmniSharpEnvironment.cs:��ப� 38
   � OmniSharp.CommandLineApplicationExtensions.CreateEnvironment(CommandLineApplication application) � D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\CommandLineApplicationExtensions.cs:��ப� 12
   � OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver.Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<Main>b__1() � D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Stdio.Driver\Program.cs:��ப� 49
   � OmniSharp.HostHelpers.Start(Func`1 action) � D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\HostHelpers.cs:��ப� 29
"B.sln" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.
[ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).
```

Comment: А как вы думаете, что значит это ошибка?

Comment: В пути могут быть только латинские символы.

Comment: Не помогло, я не знаю что может быть

Comment: А что ты делал? перенеси проект на диск С. И скачай https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/ будет намного проще чем в vscode